# Cannot debug Xamarin Project Created with Visual studio 2017 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarn.forms project created in Visual studio 2017 and working fine in Visual studio 2017 but when i trying to run  this project with debug in visual studio 2019 not working with this error **java.exe" exited with code 1  but run fine in release mode.

thanks

Comment: have you tried deleting obj/bin folders ?  If I were you i would just create a new solution and move the classes to it ,  This way you would have the latest architecture (for example latest csproj) .

Comment: I got this error before, close the VS and restart the my PC, do the same way with Ahmad ElMadi to delete the bin and obj folder, clean and rebuild. You could try it. It fixed the error for me.